# How to create named ranges using for loop in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to create named ranges using for loop script in Excel.

[image: Example dataset]

My aim is to create ranges for each rows from B to D columns, which are named after column A. E.g.: range 'alfae' contains B1:D1, and range 'alfag' contains B2:D2, and so on.

Here's the basic script that I created:

```
Sub ExampleMacro()
'
' ExampleMacro Macro
'
'
        Range("B1:D1").Select
        ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="alfae", RefersToR1C1:="=Munka1!R1C2:R1C4"
    End Sub
```

My question: how can I loop through each row in column A? And how can I name a range with the value of a cell (e.g. A1:D1="alfae"; A2:D2="alfag"; etc.)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If this is not necessarily to be done with VBA you can use "[Create names from selection](http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/418-tip-fastest-way-to-create-defined-names-in-excel)" (Ctrl + Shift + F3) in the *Formula* menu to do this for the whole Range. Or see [How to Create Named Ranges to Use in Excel Formulas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kF73uvOhA4) for an advanced mode.

Comment: @Peh - a bit of offtopic - what were you doing in order to find Ctrl+Shift+F3 as a shortcut for names from selection?

Comment: @Vityata Hover the mouse over the menu button in *Formula* menu of the Ribbon shows a tooltip (Excel 2016) Don't know if this differs in localized Office versions (I used German Office).

Comment: @Peh - in 2010 it does not show up. But still, it works! (Unfortunately I use German Office as well)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the proposed names in column **A**, try:

```
Sub WhatsInAName()
    For Each r In Columns(1).SpecialCells(2)
        Range(r.Offset(, 1), r.Offset(, 3)).Name = r.Value
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

To save some typing, you can replace:

```
Range(r.Offset(, 1), r.Offset(, 3)).Name = r.Value
```

with:

```
r.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 3).Name = r.Value
```

Comment: Using the constant cells through `SpecialCells(2)` and looping all over is an interesting approach!

Comment: @Vityata  It can be useful in cases like this one.

Comment: Yup, it is -  saves some lines for defining the last row and checking for empty values.

Comment: And I have even started to use it already here :) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47535954/5448626

Answer (score 2):

```
 sub Example()
 Dim r as range
 set r =  range("A1")
 Do
     ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=r.text, RefersToR1C1:="=Munka1!R" & r.row & "C2:R" & r.row & "C4"
     set r = r.offset(1.0)
Loop until r = ""
End SUb
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will be quite enough:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim myRange     As Range
    Dim myRow       As Range

    Set myRange = Range("A1:D4")

    For Each myRow In myRange.Rows
        If Not IsNumeric(Left, Cells(myRow.Row, 1)) Then
          ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=Cells(myRow.Row, 1), _
          RefersToR1C1:=Range(myRange(myRow.Row, 2), myRange(myRow.Row, myRow.Columns - 1))
        End If
    Next myRow

End Sub
```

Just make sure that you have some values in `A1:A4`. You may go further, updating the code. The `Left()` is used as a condition, because the named range cannot start with a number.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub MakeNamedRanges()

startrow = 1
endrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For r = startrow To endrow
    Range(Cells(r, 2), Cells(r, 4)).Select
    rangename = Cells(r, 1)
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=rangename, RefersToR1C1:="=Munka1!R" & r & "C2:R" & r & "C4"
Next r

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to loop:

```
Sub ExampleMacro()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Application.Intersect(Sheet4.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, Sheet4.Range("A:D"))
    r.CreateNames Left:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you want to call your formulas from, you can probably achieve this using the built in range names you get when you convert your data into an Excel Table (aka ListObject). Use the Ctrl + T keyboard shortcut, or select Insert>Table from the ribbon. Multi-column referencing syntax is like so:
=Table3[@[Column2]:[Column4]]
...where [Column2] and [Column4] are the names of your columns.