# VBA - Countif Range matches at least one value from array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, match

I am at a loss as how to complete this task.  I need to count a range in a sheet if at least one of the words in a cell in that range matches an array.  For example, if cell `"B2"` has a sentence with one of the words that is in the array then count as one, and simply `countif` a range if it matches with an array.  My code will better display my question, so I apologize if this is at all confusing.

```
With ThisWorkbook
    Dim Keywords As Variant
    Dim iVal As Double
    keyword = Array("*cold*", "*hot*", "*warm*", "*cool*", _
        "*temp*", "*thermostat*", "*heat*", "*temperature*", _
        "*not working*", "*see above*", "*broken*", "*freezing*", _
        "*warmer*", "*air conditioning*", "*humidity*", _
        "*humid*")
    iVal=Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B2",Range("B2").End(xlDown)),keyword)

    Dim rep As Worksheet
    Set rep = Worksheets("Report")
    rep.Range("A1") = iVal
End With
```

As I show, If one of those words in the array match in a cell in the range defined, `Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))`, then count and display value in the `Worksheets("Report").Range("A1")`.  Any and all help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What if a cell has more than one word from the array? Is it, if contains one or more?

Comment: @QHarr - Hello again and thanks for helping, again.  As long as there is one phrase, that is all I care about.  So, if it as both "air conditioning" and "cold", that would only count as 1

Comment: you also have explicitly specified a worksheet for the range to work with for the Countif

Comment: Do you mean only count as 1? And what is the name of the worksheet you are looping column B in?

Comment: @QHarr yes I do, exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compare two lists for values within each other - your `Range` and the `Array`. The easiest way to do so is through nested loop. Like this:

```
Sub TestMe()

    With ThisWorkbook

        Dim Keywords    As Variant
        Dim iVal        As Long
        Dim myRange     As Range
        Dim myCell      As Range
        Dim bCount      As Boolean
        Dim myVal       As Variant

        keyword = Array("cold", "hot", "warm", "cool", _
                        "temp", "thermostat", "heat", "temperature", _
                        "not working", "see above", "broken", "freezing", _
                        "warmer", "air conditioning", "humidity", _
                        "humid")

        Set myRange = Columns(2).SpecialCells(2)

        For Each myCell In myRange
            bCount = False

            For Each myVal In keyword
                If InStr(1, myCell, myVal, vbTextCompare) Then bCount = True
            Next myVal

            If bCount Then iVal = iVal + 1                
        Next myCell

        Debug.Print iVal
    End With

End Sub
```

The count is done whenever the flag `bCount` is set to `True`. It is reset to `False` by every iteration of the outer loop.
I would remove the `*`, as far as I am using the `InStr()` to make the check and the stars are a bit useless there.

Furthermore `Columns(2).SpecialCells(2)` returns a range, consisting only of values, which are non-formulas and non-empty in Column `B`.

Comment: Will this work if there are variations in the use of uppercase and lowercase letters?

Comment: @ACohen - if you add `vbTextCompare` to the `InStr()` it will.

Comment: Do I add that to the area where there is a 1?

Comment: @ACohen - I have added it in my code here - `If InStr(1, myCell, myVal, vbTextCompare) Then bCount = True`

Answer (score 1):

This was my answer much the same as @Vityata. Note you can use his suggestion of SpecialCells to ignore blanks when reading the range into the Array.

Note it looks for `"*Cold*"` if that is what is in the array. Put simply `"Cold"` etc ,in the array, if that is the word being looked for within the cell.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Dim Keywords As Variant
    Dim iVal As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(2)

    Keywords = Array("*cold*", "*hot*", "*warm*", "*cool*", _
                     "*temp*", "*thermostat*", "*heat*", "*temperature*", _
                     "*not working*", "*see above*", "*broken*", "*freezing*", _
                     "*warmer*", "*air conditioning*", "*humidity*", _
                     "*humid*")
    With ws

        Dim rangetoCheck()
        Dim counter1 As Long
        Dim counter2 As Long
        Dim totalCount As Long
        iVal = 0
        rangetoCheck = .Range("B2", .Range("B2").End(xlDown)).value

        For counter1 = LBound(rangetoCheck, 1) To UBound(rangetoCheck, 1)

            For counter2 = LBound(Keywords) To UBound(Keywords)

                If InStr(1, rangetoCheck(counter1, 1), Keywords(counter2), vbBinaryCompare) Then
                    iVal = iVal + 1
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next counter2

        Next counter1

    End With

    MsgBox iVal

End Sub
```